# MySql table out of bound Exception -1

Tags: java, mysql

All items are shown on the table but clicking on them gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at

```
    private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
    DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    if (model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 3).toString().equals("1"))
    {
    AvBtn.setSelected(true);
     }
    IdField.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString());
    NumberField.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1).toString());
    locationField.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 2).toString());
            UserIdField.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 4).toString());
}
```

Comment: Please post whole stack trace (not as image please). Also do not see how is this code related to MySQL database

Comment: The stack trace will tell us more about where and why this is happening. But, you want to make sure all of your rowIndex and columns are actually correct. What is the structure of the table?

Answer (score 0):

o Anisa!! Helle topin atu tek bicikleta edhe lere netbeansin te bej punen e tij.